# RabbitMQ Durability

Tags: queue, rabbitmq, message-queue, durability

I'm using rabbitMQ on docker. 
When executing the rabbitmq, I want to set the message durability `(durable/transient)`.
Is there any way to set up durability? (except when declare Queue and Exchange)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible to specify  *delivery-mode* message attribute for any published message. However, the target queue must be also durable for a message to be persisted.

See chapter *Message Attributes and Payload* in RabbitMQ [documenation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/amqp-concepts.html):

> Messages in the AMQP model have attributes. Some attributes are so
>   common that the AMQP 0-9-1 specification defines them and application
>   developers do not have to think about the exact attribute name. Some
>   examples are
>
> ```
> Content type
> Content encoding
> Routing key
> Delivery mode (persistent or not)
> Message priority
> Message publishing timestamp
> Expiration period
> Publisher application id
> ```
>
> Simply publishing a
>   message to a durable exchange or the fact that the queue(s) it is
>   routed to are durable doesn't make a message persistent: it all
>   depends on persistence mode of the message itself. Publishing messages
>   as persistent affects performance (just like with data stores,
>   durability comes at a certain cost in performance).